# Get dimensions of logo

Tags: php, logo

I have the following code installed in my header.php:

```
<h1><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'mitch_logo' ) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"></h1>
```

And in my functions.php, I have the following code:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'mitch_logo_section' , array(
    'title'       => __( 'Logo', 'mitch_logo' ),
    'priority'    => 30,
    'description' => 'Upload your logo.',
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'mitch_logo' );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'mitch_logo', array(
    'label'    => __( 'Logo', 'mitch_logo' ),
    'section'  => 'mitch_logo_section',
    'settings' => 'mitch_logo',
) ) );
```

Works great, but I want to have a div called `.logo` with the logo width and height. How I do get those?

```
.logo {
    width:{width}; // how to get width of image?
    height:{height}; // how to get height of image?
    background: ...;
}
```

Because you need width and height to get a div with background to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) for this purpose:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize(esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'mitch_logo' ) ));

echo ".logo {
    width:{$width}px;
    height:{$height}px;
    background: ...;
}";
```

If that adds a little milliseconds to your page load time, I can edit this to provide a JavaScript version of the answer :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Samuel, I want this to be fully PHP, so no javascript version is needed, thanks for the offer, though! Works great. :)

Comment: note `getimagesize` needs `allow_url_fopen` to work with URLs... though it is rarely off it could be, so if it is a public theme you may want to add a check `if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {` with a fallback to convert the URL back to a filepath to call`getimagesize` on that instead.